# Python curve fitting on pandas dataframe then add coef to new columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, curve-fitting

I have a dataframe that needs to be curve fitted per row (second order polynomial).

There are four columns, each column name denotes the x value.

Each row contains 4 `y` values corresponding to the `x` values in the column name.

For example:
Based on the code below, The fitting for the first row will take `x = [2, 5, 8, 12]` and `y = [5.91, 28.06, 67.07, 145.20]`

```
import numpy as np
import panda as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'id2': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
        'x': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12],
        'y': [5.91, 4.43, 5.22, 1.31, 4.42, 3.65, 4.45, 1.70, 3.94, 3.29, 28.06, 19.51, 23.30, 4.20, 18.61, 17.60, 18.27, 16.18, 16.81, 16.37, 67.07, 46.00, 54.95, 43.66, 42.70, 41.32, 12.69, 36.75, 41.36, 38.66, 145.20, 118.34, 16.74, 94.10, 93.45, 86.60, 26.17, 77.12, 91.42, 83.11]})

pivot_df = df.pivot_table(index=['id','id2'],columns=['x'])

[output]
>>> pivot_df
           y                      
x         2      5      8       12
id id2                            
1  A    5.91  28.06  67.07  145.20
   B    3.65  17.60  41.32   86.60
2  A    4.43  19.51  46.00  118.34
   B    4.45  18.27  12.69   26.17
3  A    5.22  23.30  54.95   16.74
   B    1.70  16.18  36.75   77.12
4  A    1.31   4.20  43.66   94.10
   B    3.94  16.81  41.36   91.42
5  A    4.42  16.37  42.70   93.45
   B    3.29  18.61  38.66   83.11
```

I want to perform the curve fitting without explicitly iterating over the rows in order to make use of the high performance under-the-hood iterating built into pandas' dataframes. I am not sure how to do so.

I wrote the code to loop through the rows anyway to show the desired output. Although the code below does work and provides the desired output, I need help in making it more concise/efficient.

```
my_coef_array = np.zeros(3)
#get the x values from the column names
x = pivot_df.columns.get_level_values(pivot_df.columns.names.index('x')).values
for index in pivot_df.index:
    my_coef_array = np.vstack((my_coef_array,np.polyfit(x, pivot_df.loc[index].values, 2)))
my_coef_array = my_coef_array[1:,:]
pivot_df['m2'] = my_coef_array[:,0]
pivot_df['m1'] = my_coef_array[:,1]
pivot_df['c'] = my_coef_array[:,2]

[output]
 >>> pivot_df
           y                              m2         m1          c
x          2      5      8      12                                
id id2                                                            
1  A    5.91  28.06  67.07  145.20  0.934379   0.848422   0.471170
   B    3.65  17.60  41.32   86.60  0.510664   1.156009  -0.767408
2  A    4.43  19.51  46.00  118.34  1.034594  -3.221912   7.518221
   B    4.45  18.27  12.69   26.17 -0.015300   2.045216   2.496306
3  A    5.22  23.30  54.95   16.74 -1.356997  20.827407 -35.130416
   B    1.70  16.18  36.75   77.12  0.410485   1.772052  -3.345097
4  A    1.31   4.20  43.66   94.10  0.803630  -1.577705  -1.148066
   B    3.94  16.81  41.36   91.42  0.631377  -0.085651   1.551586
5  A    4.42  16.37  42.70   93.45  0.659044  -0.278738   2.068114
   B    3.29  18.61  38.66   83.11  0.478171   1.218486  -0.638888
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following `numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit` which is an alternative to `np.polyfit` that takes a 2-D array for y.

Starting your code from x, I get the following:

```
my_coef_array = pd.DataFrame(np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(x, pivot_df.T.values, 2)).T
my_coef_array.index = pivot_df.index
my_coef_array.columns = ['c', 'm1', 'm2']

pivot_df = pivot_df.join(my_coef_array)
```