# Python exponential curve fitting in pandas: Define function parameters per row

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, curve-fitting, exponential-distribution

my dataframe [11 x 300], where the column header equals 'x' ([0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2,2.25,2.5,2.75,3,3.25]), and each row-value represents 'y' for. Each row can be described by an exponential function in the following format : a * x ^k + b.

The goal is to add three additional columns, describing a, k and b for that specific row. Just like: [Python curve fitting on pandas dataframe then add coef to new columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623562/python-curve-fitting-on-pandas-dataframe-then-add-coef-to-new-columns)

Instead of a polynomial function, my data needs be described in the following format: a * x **k + b.

As I cannot find any solution to derive the coefficients by using np.polyfit, I split my dataframe into different lists.

---

```
x  = np.array([0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2,2.25,2.5,2.75,3,3.25])
y1  = np.array([288.79,238.32,199.42,181.22,165.50,154.74,152.25,152.26,144.81,144.81,144.81])
y2 = np.array([309.92,255.75,214.02,194.48,177.61,166.06,163.40,163.40,155.41,155.41,155.41])
...
y300 = np.array([352.18,290.63,243.20,221.00,201.83,188.71,185.68,185.68,176.60,176.60,176.60])

def func(x,a,k,b):
    return a * (x**k) + b

popt1, pcov = curve_fit(func,x,y1, p0 = (300,-0.5,0))
...
popt300, pcov = curve_fit(func,x,y300, p0 = (300,-0.5,0))

output: 
popt1 
[107.73727907  -1.545475   123.48621504]
...
popt300
[131.38411712  -1.5454452  150.59522147
```

---

This works, when I split all dataframe rows into lists and define popt for every list/row.
Avoiding to split all 300 columns - I prefer to apply the same methodology as [Python curve fitting on pandas dataframe then add coef to new columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623562/python-curve-fitting-on-pandas-dataframe-then-add-coef-to-new-columns)

---

my_coep_array = pd.DataFrame(np.polyfit(x, df.values,1)).T

---

But how to define my np.polyfit - a * x **k + b?

Comment: raise x to power k and use `np.polyfit` with `deg = 1`?

Comment: k is unknown and depends on the distributon.

Comment: Okay, what I have done now is the following:

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack((x,yn)))
df = df.T

def func(x,a,k,b):
    return a * (x**k) + b

for i in range(1, numcols):
     popt[i], pcov[i] = curve_fit(func, df.iloc[0] , df.iloc[i], p0 = (300,-0.5,0))

Comment: The only thing is that the three variables for each result i = 0 - 300 needs to be stored in each column ..